# Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1 Authentication Required - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, gmail

I have an issue with authentication to my gmail account in Laravel app.

I have tried with ssl(port: 465) and also tls(port: 587) but it still doesn't work.

Here are the my .env file and config/mail.php files. Please help me out

config/mail.php file:

```
<?php

return [

'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com'),

'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),

'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'EMAIL_ADDRESS'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'NAME'),
],

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),

'username' => env('username'),

'password' => env('password'),

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
    ],
],

];
```

.env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=****@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD="****"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you forgot to remove your password from the confg/mail.php snippet? If yes, edit it out and raise a flag for moderator attention, and ask to remove the editing history. And change it just to be on the secure side.

Comment: Review|Help and Improvement: formatted code

Answer (score 1):

First deceit you are going to use **.env** file or **mail.php**
if **.env** file use this

```
    return [

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com'),

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', ''),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', ''),
    ],

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME',''),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD',''),

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

    ];

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=****@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD="****"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

and if you are going to use **mail.php** file then use like this don't confuse both files

```
return [

        'driver' => 'smtp',

        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',

        'port' => 465,

        'from' => [
            'address' => '',
            'name' => '',
        ],

        'encryption' => 'ssl',

        'username' => '',

        'password' => '',

        'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

        'markdown' => [
            'theme' => 'default',

            'paths' => [
                resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
            ],
        ],

        ];
```